# Geometrical meaning of gradient

Tags: vector-analysis

I'm having a hard time understanding the geometrical meaning of the gradient. I understand how to calculate it on theory, given a function. But what if **we don't have the function**, but just a 3d graphic with points like this one:

[image]

I assume if I am able to find the gradients in every corner point of every "rectangle", Ill easily get the whole gradient, but how can I do that? What exactly does the gradient in this case? Should I compare the areas of all neighbour rectangles to see where there's a slope? Should I somehow check in which direction the area changes?

Anything easily explained will be of great help to my understanding, thank you.

Comment: Measure the slope in the X direction and in the Y direction. That would be enough. Gradient is just a vector of partial derivatives. If you have a good grasp on the geometric meaning of the derivative, you are good. The relative size and the signs of the vector components (the x and y derivatives) will tell you the direction of the gradient vector

Comment: Gradient is just a vector of partial derivatives -> but since we don't have a given function, how to find the derivatives? ; geometric meaning of the derivative -> it's the slope, right?

Comment: Right. You can approximate derivative from values at grid points. Using the usual definition.

Comment: @vedsil Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks! cdn.sstatic.net/img/faq/faq-accept-answer.png

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a function $z=f(x,y)$ the gradient vector in $(x_0,y_0)$ is

$$\nabla f(x_0,y_0)=f_x(x_0,y_0)\,\vec i+f_y(x_0,y_0)\,\vec j$$

Note that it is defined in the plane $(x,y)$ and represent geometrically the direction with **maximum slope** of the graph  $z=f(x,y)$ and the maximum slope is given  by the norm i.e."lenght of the gradient" vector.

Note also that by the gradient we can calculate the **directional derivative** for every direction defined by a vector $\vec v$ by the doct product with the gradient, that is:

$$f_{\vec v}=\frac {\partial f}{\partial \vec v}=\nabla \cdot \vec v$$

Note that in your graph near the corner point gradient vector tends to vanish since the slope is almost zero.

Comment: But what if we dont have this function f, but just the coordinates of all points? Is there a way to calculate the slope then?

Comment: @vedsil if you have only the values at discrete points we need to use numerical method to estimate the second derivatives at a point, as for example finite difference methods

Comment: So there isn't really a geometrical approach to it?

Comment: @vedsil The geometrical approach is to observe that at the corners th graph becomes flat and thus the gradient vanishes, but it is a qualitative argument